# What happens if I capture two new types of aliens on a single mission?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm still fairly early in the game, and often find myself on missions where there are two types of aliens present that I have yet to bring back alive. I only have one containment facility, so I was wondering what would happen if I managed two subdue two new alien species. Seeing how capturing aliens is rather challenging, I would hate for my efforts to go to waste.

Would it matter if I had additional alien containment facilities (if that is at all possible, I admit I did not check)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like in the original, one Alien Containment is all you need.

If you capture two aliens on one map, both will be available for interrogation.

Comment: Gotta catch 'em all.

Comment: That's good to know. I imagine I would get both cinematics in succession in that case, then?

Comment: You see a cinematic when you start an interrogation project.

Comment: You also have somewhat weird effect if you capture an outsider before, or simultaneously, with your first other live alien. You'd see the "outsider shard" cinematic with Shen and Vahlen talking anbout it being an "antenna", but then you still have to cature and research another alien to get outsider shard research,